# What is a "bubble mix"?

Tags: genre, terminology, remix

A coworker of mine described Girl Talk's *All Day* as "a bubble mix" when I introduced it to him. It sounded a bit derisive, actually.

I've never heard that term before, and all Google was no help either: it yielded lots of recipes for making your own bubble mix — for blowing bubbles. The few music related links it turned up, were pieces of music that were named "Some song (bubble mix)", which indicates that it *is* a musical term, just not one I know.

So what is a bubble mix?

Comment: People commonly use the term "bubble gum" to refer to music they consider vapid, often pop music. Perhaps that is what he meant. Ask him!

Comment: @ZacRay "Bubble Mix" was also the title of Aqua's second album - they were quite popular in Europe when I was a kid. Considering the style they played, the term may be somehow connected to bubble gum music. You may remember the song "Barbie Girl"

Comment: It sounds synonymous with "bubblegum" pop, too.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments it could be synonymous with [Bubble Gum Pop music:](http://www.allmusic.com/subgenre/bubblegum-ma0000002487)

- Lightweight catchy pop music
- > It was simple, melodic, and light as feather -- neither the lyrics or
  >   the music had much substance.

[Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubblegum_pop)

Since Bubble gum pop can be refered to as simply bubble gum. A bubble gum mix could refer to a collection of bubble gum music or bubble gum music that was [remixed](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remix). Or even some elements that are mixed into one song.